# Link external CSS stylesheet with Shopify product page

Tags: html, css, shopify

I usually put these below code in order to do additional styling for my product page. But I am looking for a way where I would like to link CSS style sheet in the product page and do the CSS designing in a different directory, example: "assets/custom.css".

So how do I link the below styles made under .

```
<style>
.checkmarks li {
  list-style-type: none;
background: url("https://i.imgur.com/FqEWdiJ.png") 0px 5px no-repeat;
background-size: 20px;
padding-left: 30px;
  line-height: 200%;
}
</style>

<ul class="checkmarks">
<li>First</li>
<li>Second</li>
<li>Third</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a file in the `assets` folder, you can access it using the `asset_url` filter in Liquid.  (Reference: https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/filters/url-filters#asset_url)

If you create your stylesheet as `assets/custom.css` you can get the URL using:

```
{{ 'custom.css' | asset_url }}
```

Since it's a stylesheet, you can add on the `stylesheet_tag` filter to also have Shopify automatically make it into an appropriate HTML tag for you:

```
{{ 'custom.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
```

One further possible improvement would be to make your stylesheet a `scss` file rather than a standard `css` file.  This allows you to use some fancy features that help keep longer CSS files more readable/maintainable. Additionally, Shopify will minify a `scss` file when it compiles everything into a final `css` file - which means the file size will be slightly smaller because all of the whitespace gets stripped out. If you decide to do this, the compiled (browser-friendly) version of the file is accessed as `<filename>.scss.css` - so `custom.scss` could be put in as:

```
{{ 'custom.scss.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
```

Finally, if you want this file to only appear on your `product` pages, you can either:

- Place this code inside your `templates/product.liquid` file, or
- Place this code in the `layout/theme.liquid` file, wrapped in a simple template check to see if we are on a product page:

  ```
  {% if template.name == 'product' %}
   {{ 'custom.scss.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
  {% endif %}
  ```